# C# winforms DGV Add a button to a datagrid with variable text

Tags: data-binding, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I know how to add a button to a [datagridview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms). What I am having a problem with is changing the text displayed based on whether a associated record exists in another table. I would like to change the text on the button to "View SR" or "Add SR" depending on if a service request exists for the record. if it even possible, how I would go about this ?

[image: Screen Print]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to capture the exact cell and cast it in a Grid View Button Cell to adjust the value displayed. Following is a tried solution:

```
            if (SomeTrueValue)
            {
                ((DataGridViewButtonCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Value = "Hello";
            }
            else
            {
                ((DataGridViewButtonCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Value = "World";
            }
```